# When using V.A.T.S., the enemy always dies?

Tags: fallout-3

From what little I've read online, using V.A.T.S. I should be able to take out non-vital body-parts, like arms and legs. When I target such limbs, however, the opponent always seems to die before any crippling occurs.

Is this normal? Will it get better when my aim improves? Is it because of my choice of weapon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of factors that would affect this. As you've mentioned, weapon choice plays a factor, as does the difficulty setting. Setting a higher difficulty makes enemies more resistant to damage, but the 'crippling' chance stays about the same.

There is a weapon you can build once you get the schematic (called the Dart Gun - it uses Radscorpion Glands) which instantly paralyzes body parts when they are targeted and does little damage. If you don't want to up the difficulty, I suggest building one of them if you want to cripple first.

Answer (score 8):

Limbs have health independent of the creature you're fighting.  You can see this health in VATS - just above the percentage chance to hit, there is a bar that decreases as you do damage to a particular body part.  (You can see that on [this screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fallout_3_V.A.T.S._Screen.PNG) which is hosted on Wikipedia)

You can cripple limbs by completely emptying this bar before killing an enemy.  There are weapons that do [bonus limb damage](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_(weapon)) as well as ones that do [primarily limb damage](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dart_gun) that can help with this.  Weapons also have a similar bar, and this represents their condition.

The tricky part can sometimes be doing this *before* you kill an enemy - doing damage to a limb also does overall health damage, so if you do too much overall damage without completely damaging a limb, the creature will die rather than become crippled.  On the other hand, if you manage to hit a limb hard enough and cripple it while killing the enemy, you'll often get a rather gory dismemberment or similar result.

However, there's not much benefit to crippling things without killing them - typically the only reason you'd want to try to cripple is if you're facing off against a tough enemy and you need an advantage.  For instance, crippling an enemy's legs will allow you to kite it easier, or get away if you can't kill it, while crippling an enemy's arm will cause them to drop any weapons they are holding in that arm.